# AngularJS ng-change does not work when get request with Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using ...

- Ruby on Rails 5
- AngularJS 1.3.20
- Chrome or FireFox Browser

It seems ng-change event does not work, when I request get method like link from other page. But when I user POST request to next page, it works.

When I change select box value, onchange event is not happen. I expect ng-change
 should reach changeHandler function in sample.js and console.log("ChangeHandler!!!") show up.

In addition, I use Ruby on Rails application template. So ng-app and ng-controller is same as index1.html and index2.html.

** Additional Info
I tried Chrome ng-inspector for AngularJS Tool. But There is no angular panel shown up. But once reload same page, it shows up. What happend?

index1.html.erb

```
<html lang="ja" ng-app="MyApp">
<body ng-controller="MyController">

<!-- For GET Method Request -->
  <div>
    <%= link_to 'Index2', sample_index2_path %>
  </div>

  <!-- For POST Method Request -->
  <div>
    <%= form_tag sample_index2_path do %>
      <%= button_tag "Click" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index2.html.erb

```
<html lang="ja" ng-app="MyApp">
<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <div>
    <form>
      <select id="eventTest" ng-model="eventTest" ng-change="changeHandler()">
        <option value="1">AAA</option>
        <option value="2">BBB</option>
        <option value="3">CCC</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

sample.js

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
    .controller("MyController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.eventTest;

    $scope.changeHandler = function () {
        console.log("ChangeHandler!!!");
    };
}]);
```

This works only POST, or Get and reload Browser.
There are any difference between output HTML source code GET and POST.
I'm stack over 3 days.

Please let me know and advice for me.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: my english does not make sence?

Comment: is 'MyController' loaded in index2.html? Put a console.log in MyController to verify

Comment: Also how are you defining MyController, is it with ng-controller? Could be an angular problem and not rails

Comment: Sorry, I added html contents too.

Comment: And I tried plain HTML with same module without RoR. It works well. Is that problem in rendering in RoR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why Angular Module does not work properly was JavaScript lib turbolinks.
I fixed this by modifying default setting reload -> false, or erasing data-turbolinks-track.

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

↓↓↓↓

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'false' %>
```